# Array with colon

Tags: php

### SOLVED:

`getDimesions()` ... google has made a type error.. LOL

---

facing some problems with array with colon in the name,

my $result is containing

```
   gapiReportEntry::__set_state(array(
'metrics' => 
 array (
    'uniquePageviews' => 1523,
 ),
 'dimensions' => 
   array (
  'pagePath' => '/',
 'pageTitle' => 'Eventyrgolf',
 'source' => 'google',
'medium' => 'organic',
'campaign' => '(not set)',
),
))
gapiReportEntry::__set_state(array(
  'metrics' => 
 array (
        'uniquePageviews' => 210,
  ),
  'dimensions' => 
 array (
'pagePath' => '/dk/greenfee-og-banen-8/',
'pageTitle' => 'Greenfee og Banen',
'source' => 'google',
'medium' => 'organic',
'campaign' => '(not set)',
```

),
 ))
But some how i cannot get the "dimensions:private"... What to do?

I tried print_r():

```
 $result->{"dimensions:private"}
 $result['dimensions:private']
 $result->dimensions
```

Full code:

```
 $ga->requestReportData($profileId, $dimensions, $metrics, $sort, null, $fromDate, $toDate, 2,   30);

foreach ($ga->getResults() as $result) {


 print_r($result->dimensions);
 }
```

Comment: `$result->dimensions` should work, whats the error?

Comment: I am not getting any data out.

Comment: Paste the code here, including the variable declaration one

Comment: your updated code does not reflect your problem anymore...

Answer (score 0):

The `dimensions` property of `$result` object is private. That means it can be accessed only by objects of the same class.

Check if your `gapiReportEntry` class contains so called getter, that is a mathod which can access the property `dimensions` and return it's value to you. Look for something like `getDimensions`.

Read more about class field visibility here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

**EDIT**
If your `gapiReportEntry` is a google analitics report, then [this docs](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ftwbzhao/CIer-/class-gapiReportEntry.html) says that there is a getDimensions() method, so just call

```
$result->getDimensions();
```

**EDIT #2**

As suggested in comment, the class seems to have misspeled method name. The actual method is named `getDim**es**ions`:

```
$result->getDimesions();
```

Comment: Some how it doesnt return anything, $result->getDimensions(); ... but there is data in it.. How to fix it?

Comment: LOL google has made a error ... its getDimesions() not getDimeseons

Answer (score 0):

your `$result` is not an array, but an object. if you `var_dump` an object, you see it's contents, which in your case is an object with 2 private variables `metrics` and `dimensions`. To access these, the object probably has some accessors:

```
$result->getMetrics();
$result->getDimensions();
```

Comment: getDimensions is not returning anything...? :(

Comment: check out the `gapiReportEntry` class source code, and use it's methods. [maybe this will help](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/ftwbzhao/CIer-/class-gapiReportEntry.html)

Answer (score -1):

Private is a reserved keyword in PHP and you should be scaping colon ":" with a backslash before it.

Comment: inside a string, there is no such thing as a reserved keyword... and escaping a colon is not needed.